# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence?

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror, dummy-variable

Why am i getting this error message?

Here are the variables that are included in my code. The columns they include are all dummy variables:

```
country_cols = wine_dummies.loc[:, 'country_Chile':'country_US']
variety_cols = wine_dummies.loc[:, 'variety_Cabernet 
Sauvignon':'variety_Zinfandel']
pricecat_cols = wine_dummies.loc[:, 'price_category_low':]
```

Here is the code that is throwing the error (it is throwing the error at "X = wine[feature_cols_1]":

```
feature_cols_1 = ['price', country_cols, variety_cols, 'year']
feature_cols_2 = [pricecat_cols, country_cols, variety_cols, 'year']

X = wine[feature_cols_1] <---ERROR
y = wine['points']
```

Here is the head of my dataframe:

```
country designation points  price   province    variety      year   ... variety_Riesling    variety_Rosé    variety_Sangiovese  variety_Sauvignon Blanc variety_Syrah   variety_Tempranillo variety_White Blend variety_Zinfandel   price_category_low  price_category_med
Portugal    Avidagos    87  15.0    Douro   Portuguese Red  2011.0  ... 0  0    0   0   0   0   0   0   1 0
```

^ each dummy variable (0s and 1s) after "..." corresponds to each column after "..."

Comment: Did you look at the output of `country_cols = wine_dummies.loc[:, 'country_Chile':'country_US']`?

Comment: yes, it outputs a dataframe that includes those columns with a uint8 dtype

Comment: columns: 'country_Chile country_France country_Germany country_Italy country_Portugal country_Spain country_US'
Row 1:    '1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0'

Comment: Exactly, so when you do `X = wine[feature_cols_1]` you're actually doing `X = wine['price', a_full_df, a full_df, 'year']`. That doesn't make sense, and that's what the error is telling you about.

Comment: thanks, do you know how I can adjust my code so that "feature_cols_1" includes all of the columns in "country_cols, variety_cols, and pricecat_cols?" I'm really just doing this so I don't have to type each column name into the "feature_cols_1" variable

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provided a [mcve]...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually quite cumbersome, so it's only going to be useful if you have lots of columns between `'country_Chile':'country_US'`. In the below example, I'm deliberately dropping the `a` column in `middle_columns` by taking the column indices.

This is using [`pandas.Index.get_loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) to find the indices of the start and end columns, which can then be used as a slice on the full list of dataframe columns. Then it unpacks that list using `*` into the final list of columns.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [2, 3, 4], 'c': [3, 4, 5], 
                   'd': [4, 5, 6], 'wine': ['happy', 'drunk', 'sad'],
                   'year': [2002, 2003, 2019]})

middle_columns = df.columns[df.columns.get_loc('b'):df.columns.get_loc('d')+1]
all_cols = ['wine', *middle_columns, 'year']
X = df[all_cols]
```

The reason your current approach doesn't work is that `feature_cols_1 = ['price', country_cols, variety_cols, 'year']` returns a list of strings *and* dataframes, that you then try to use as columns to a second dataframe.

Comment: Thanks, I think you're leading me in the right direction. Almost there. I apologize for all of the follow up questions: I used your code, but now I'm getting this error "unhashable type: 'Index'" am i doing something wrong?

Comment: That sounds almost certainly like a mistranslation of my approach. At a guess, you're missing a `get_loc` but I really can't know how that error comes about

Comment: This worked! Thank you! Yes, it was a mistranslation. I didn't unpack using *.